# Can Firebug be more useful at debugging? Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

Figured out how to make my javascript work, but it took a really, really, really long time.  Enough to make me wish to continue avoiding javascript.  I started with a complex page, and kept reducing it and changing it bit by bit to a simple example that worked.

Eventually figured out that square brackets have to be escaped with two backslashes.  But not always - apparently in selectors -- but not in the .attr('id', 'element[' + newNum + ']' context, then escaping there is wrong.

How could I have figured this out quicker?  I haven't written much javascript or used Firebug much, because it seems like I waste so much time where in c++ errors would (often) have been faster to find, that I get irritated at javascript and avoid using it.

Running the code that doesn't work with Firebug open shows no errors.  I've tried on the script and console tab.

**When this button is clicked, there's no visible reaction.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
          var num = $('.element').length-1;
          var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
          var newElem = $('#element[' + num + ']').clone().attr('id', 'element[' + newNum + ']');
          $('#element[' + num + ']').after(newElem);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <div id="element[0]" class="element">
        description
        <input type="text" name="element[0][description]" id="element[0][description]" value="desc0" />
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**When this button is clicked, a new list element is created as intended.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num = $('.element').length-1;
            var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
            var newElem = $('#element\\[' + num + '\\]').clone().attr('id', 'element[' + newNum + ']');
            $('#element\\[' + num + '\\]').after(newElem);
          });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <div id="element[0]" class="element">
        description
        <input type="text" name="element[0][description]" id="element[0][description]" value="desc0" />
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a) use an IDE: eclipse, WebMatrix is pretty good, or a thousand others. b) Chrome Dev Tools beats firebug (fact). c) occasional checks with something like JSLint is good for long term best-practice coding. There's a plugin for notepad++ that I like. d) Patience. Any move from language 1 to language 2 instantiates feelings of "I wish language 2 was more like language 1". But Javascript really is great, if not a little different.

Comment: I find reading [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) most of the time extremely helpful: *"To use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: ``\\``."* In this case this is a *user error*. No tool  can know what you actually intended to do and that you meant to use `[]` literally. This is something which comes with experience. The more you use the language/library, the more familiar you become with it.

Answer (score 2):

In selectors, `[]` have special meaning. It signifies finding an attribute. For example, the following code looks for input of type file:

```
var fileInputs = $('input[type=file]');
```

I don't know why you are using `[]` for your id, you can just go with `elementN` where `N` is a number.

Additionally, though JS is an OOP language, avoid using the `new` syntax in creating native objects (there are exceptions though, like predetermined-length arrays). Your `newNum` could be created like this:

```
var newNum = num + 1;
```

As for Firebug, it's one of the most preferred debugging tools. If it does not report anything, then it's either their bug, or your code working just fine, but not the way you expected it to.

Comment: $('#element[' + num + ']') isn't going to find an object, since it's treating num as looking for an attribute. I would hope that in a debugger, you'd at least get a warning that you were trying to invoke the .clone() function to a non-existent object. I'm thinking of this along the lines of dereferencing a null pointer in c++, a segfault.  I can see the desire not to stop execution, but I'd love to see a warning on it. Example is from a more complicated page, where ids are like aaa[#][bbb][#][ccc] to represent an array of arrays of objects with multiple properties. Liked that over aaa#bbb#ccc.

Comment: ... I could check every selector usage to see if it returned an empty object/empty array/whatever the proper way to look at it is, but I'd hope a debugger would at least warn if not doing that, and trying to use the empty object instead.

Comment: ... Or, to not annoy people who regularly want to write code with the intent of often using empty objects, at least an option in the debugger to warn on this case.

Comment: @user1902689 an empty object is useful, especially if you do a `length` test to check for existence of elements. If 0 `length`, no match, no such elements in the DOM... or you got your selector wrong and matched the wrong things.